# Why can't I export a named export from my module?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have two things I want to export from my module, `Foo` and `Bar`. How do I export `Foo` as the default and `Bar` as a normal export?

I have tried this but it did not work:

```
export Bar;
export default Foo;
```

Comment: Are you saying that `./components` refers to that index.js file, and that the index.js file contains the exports you've shown in your second snippet?

Comment: YES that is true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a syntax error, that's why it's not exporting the named export. When you're exporting a named export, the correct syntax is:

```
export { name1, name2, …, nameN };
```

You need the curly braces around your named export like so:

```
export { Bar };
export default Foo;
```

That's the correct syntax to export `Bar` as a named export. Read the documentation on `export` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

---

Note that your terminology is wrong. A module is a JavaScript file. What you're exporting (variables, functions, etc.) are *names*, not modules themselves. You export *names*, not modules.

Comment: I know it's weird! Hah! The goal is that I have each component with a reducer file and an index.js file an I want to provide both the component and the reducer through the index.js file. that's better than writing long paths to deep components in the app structure.

Comment: Yeaaaah! When I import the App and reducer to the index.js file and then export them; it export when I export the component as default but it does not export the reducer as named export! Thanx for you time I am sorry!